# window.showmodeldialogue should recieve a parameter from dropdown

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am displaying a form in pop up using window.showmodeldialog. The form which is being displayed in pop up contains multiple panels.I want to show/hide panel on the basis of dropdown value supplied as a parameter.
Please help.

[image: DropDown value to be selected]

[image: Value Selected]

[image: Pop up Opened on the basis of selected value]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.open` method and use the object returned by that to access the new window instance. The returned object can be used to access properties and methods of the new window provided it complies with Same origin policy security requirements.

```
var url="url to the new page here";
var newWindow = window.open(url);
```

And in the new window's js code, you can create a method like

```
function updateOptions(selection)
{
   alert("call reecived from parent");
   //Hide or show based on selection value
}
```

When user changes something on the parent window, you may call the `updateOptions()` method on the handle received from the window.open method.

```
newWindow.updateOptions("PassSomeRealValuesHere");
```

Comment: i think window.open works only in windows not in web.